# ¿Qué sucede en el proceso de crear un exe a partir de un código de ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador, masm

Para crear un ejecutable a partir de archivo con extensión asm se hace lo siguiente:

```
masm.exe codigo.asm  
link.exe codigo.obj
```

Ahora ya podemos probar el código escribiendo:

```
codigo.exe
```

Pero tengo la duda de saber que pasa cuando se genera el **obj** a partir del **asm (ensamble)**,  y cuando se genera el **exe** a partir del **obj (enlace)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR**: Si tienes un sólo archivo de código, basta con pasarlo por argumento al compilador, este se encargará de asignar toda la cabecera de ejecutable y demás; lo dulce pasa cuando tienes más de un archivo, los archivos con extensión `.asm` no són archivos de "ensamble" son archivos de código fuente como cualquier otro, al pasarlos como argumento al ensamblador, simplemente se produce un binario compilado, al pasarlo por el enlazador, se terminan de asignar las referencias absolutas a los miembros que tiene dicho binario.
>
> Si tienes un método `main()` en un binario *compilado* cuya dirección es `0x00000010`, al enlazarlo, si hay `0xDAD00000` direcciones de memoria utilizadas por todas las librerías que utilizas, entonces, el punto de entrada de tu aplicación se colocará en la dirección de memoria `0xDAD00010`, durante la etapa que propones sólo ocurren los calculos de las direcciones definitivas y la resolución de símbolos externos.

---

Durante el proceso de creación de un ejecutable podemos describir las siguientes fases:

```
Archivos de código fuente > Compilador > Enlazador > Ejecutable final.
```

Entonces describimos algunos terminos:

- Ensamblador: Es programa diseñado para traducir Mnemónicos<sup>1</sup> a código máquina para una plataforma "X".

¿En qué se diferencia esto de un compilador?

Hoy en día la gran mayoría de lenguajes de programación cuenta con una serie de librerías que contienen métodos útiles para todo programador, esto es lo que se puede conocer como un "Binario precompilado", pero estos binarios no hacen nada más que lo que describen, dentro de estos se encuentran los métodos correspondientes a su respectiva librería con una dirección base `0x00000000`, o sea, relativa.

- Compilador: Es un programa diseñado para traducir sentencias en un lenguaje de alto nivel y proveer la salida especificada si dicho software lo soporta, ya sea, el código ensamblador, o el mismo código expandiendo las macros de preprocesador o un ejecutable sólo compilado.

Bien, dicho esto, ver que un ensamblador no es muy diferente de un compilador, salvo que este último hace unas cuantas tareas para proveer el binario ejecutable final; el ensamblador procesa el código pasado por entrada y produce un binario absoluto, a menos que se le indique que aún hay direcciones sin resolver, considera la siguiente entrada en el lenguaje de programación C:

- Archivo `A.c`:

  ```
  extern int A();                /* Declaramos una funcion externa. */
  int main(void) { return A(); } /* La llamamos desde main() */
  ```
- Archivo `B.c`:

  ```
  int A() {
      return 42; /* Definimos la función, */
  }
  ```

Si intentamos compilar y enlazar sólo el archivo `A.c`, el compilador nos mostrará un error de enlazado diciendo que la dirección de la función `A` no pudo ser *resuelta* y por ende, no se le puede generar un ejecutable para ese archivo.

Ahora bien, si compilamos sin enlazar el archivo, el compilador no arrojará ningun error, debido a que no intentó enlazarlo, sin embargo, este archivo producido por el compilador es sólo un archivo objeto sin punto de entrada<sup>2</sup> el cual necesita al enlazador para unir una "X" cantidad de binarios que necesiten de las funciones llamadas en tu archivo objeto.

Entonces, para obetener el ejecutable, necesitamos compilar sin enlazar los archivos `A.c` y `B.c`, debido a que uno contiene la declaración de función y el otro su definición<sup>3</sup>, luego los enlaza y produce el ejecutable final.

---

> Con respecto a los compiladores, hoy en día prácticamente todos tienen un enlazador, un ensamblador y un cargador interno, haciendo que el proceso *sea* invisible para el desarrollador, es por esto que he descrito lo que dije en las primeras líneas de mi respuesta.

---

<sup>1</sup>: [Del inglés *mnemonic* (Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnem%C3%B3nico)
<sup>2</sup>: Por ejemplo: La funcion `main()`, la primera que se llama al ejecutar el programa.
<sup>3</sup>: Declarar y definir no es lo mismo, la declaración sólo conoce la existencia del miembro, mientras que su definición asegura el comportamiento del mismo.

Answer (score 1):

El **ensamblado** (assembling) comprueba tu código y lo convierte en lenguaje máquina en forma de un fichero obj, el cual aún no se puede ejecutar directamente como si fuera un programa.

El **enlazado** (linking) combina varios objetos, uno será tu código ensamblado y los otros pueden ser librerías u otros ficheros de tu proyecto. Reordena internamente las posiciones de memoria de algunos objetos del código (offsets), añade la cabeceras necesarias para que el sistema operativo entienda que es un fichero ejecutable y escribe el fichero .EXE o .COM en disco.